# What does mongoose's Model.updateOne return value mean?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So my question is short and simple: 
What do these describe?

```
{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Mongoose updateOne [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-updateOne),

> n; // Number of documents matched 
> nModified; // Number of documents modified 
> ok; // 1 if no errors occurred

You can also visit the MongoDB updateOne [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#returns),

> The method returns a document that contains:
>
> `matchedCount` containing the number of matched documents 
> `modifiedCount` containing the number of modified documents 
> `upsertedId` containing the `_id` for the upserted document. 
> A boolean `acknowledged` as `true` if the operation ran with [write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#std-term-write-concern) or `false` if write concern was disabled